# How to align check boxes in one line?

Tags: html, css

I have two check-boxes, I want to align these check-box in one line. I am not able to align following check-box in one line, please tell me how to do

```
<div class="form-group">
  <label class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 control-label">From:*</label>
  <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3">
     <input type="checkbox" ng-model="checkbox1" >
  </div>

  <label class="col-lg-2 col-md-9 control-label">To:*</label>
  <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3">
     <input type="checkbox" ng-model="checkbox2" >
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove div's around inputs, or give all elements `float:left`

Answer (score 0):

You could use inline-block elements. You need to set font-size to 0 on main container to be able to use 100% in total width od the two elements per row.

```
.form-group{
 font-size:0;
}

.form-group label{
 display: inline-block;
 width: 40%
 font-size: 14px;
}

.form-group div{
 display: inline-block;
 width: 60%
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Pretty sure its because of your grid system that you are using to seperate each class with "col-lg-3 col-md-3 etc. WHen i minimize my browser it is on two seperate lines but when i expand my browser your code shows it on the same line. You can fix it with something like this

```
<div class="form-group">
<div class="col-lg-12">
    <label class="control-label">From:*</label>
    <input type="checkbox" ng-model="checkbox1" >

    <label class="control-label">To:*</label>
    <input type="checkbox" ng-model="checkbox2" >
</div>
</div>
```